# Stored procedure to find Highest Scores in SQL table

Tags: sql

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
| Name  |   Date    | Score |
+-------+-----------+-------+
| Name1 | 1/3/2016  |    80 |
| Name2 | 1/5/2016  |    76 |
| Name3 | 1/29/2016 |    77 |
| Name4 | 1/30/2016 |    40 |
| Name4 | 1/17/2016 |    79 |
| Name5 | 1/1/2016  |    90 |
| Name2 | 1/3/2016  |    79 |
| Name5 | 1/27/2016 |    92 |
| Name2 | 1/27/2016 |    99 |
| Name1 | 1/21/2016 |    93 |
| Name2 | 1/3/2016  |    70 |
| Name1 | 2/15/2016 |    80 |
| Name3 | 3/31/2016 |    84 |
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

I have this table and need to find the highest score for each name in a given period of time (i.e. between 01/01/2016 and 01/31/2016) and display Name, Date and Highest Score.

Please help! Thank you - Humberto Goez

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.  What have you tried and found to not work as you wanted?

Comment: What about collisions?  If Name1 scored 99 on two different dates?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Procedural code is **highly** vendor-specific, thus we need to know what actual system you're using....

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a problem with duplicate rows, as you don't have a primary key shown.  This query would work, but it would be better to employ a primary key

Of course, this is just the SQL...

```
SELECT Name, [Date], Score
FROM MyTable T1
WHERE T1.Score = (SELECT MAX(T2.Score) 
                  FROM MyTable T2 
                  WHERE T2.Name = T1.Name)
    AND [Date] >= @StartDate
    AND [Date] <= @EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQL Server` then you could use:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2016-01-01T00:00:00'
       ,@end_date DATE = '2016-01-31T00:00:00';

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [Name],[Date],[Score]
FROM tab_name t
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
ORDER BY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Score DESC);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/VAN9095)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have the following Stored Procedure

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is CTE. Sample query looks like this:

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '2016-01-01',
        @EndDate datetime = '2016-06-01'
;with scores as (
SELECT Name, [Date], Score,
row_number() over(partition by name /*start over each name*/ 
                  order by Score desc /*top first*/,[Date] /*earlier first*/) rn
FROM MyTable
)
select * from scores
where rn = 1
```